# What if configuring the Vagrant File to forward_port does not work; any alternatives?

Tags: vagrant, jupyter-notebook

So I've spent couple of days trying to find a fix around getting Jupyter notebook to launch in a VM using vagrant.

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

Seems to be the most common solution; however my vagrant file differs from what the rest have recommended to change and I could not find a suitable reference and I'm pretty much stuck at the moment.

[Reference to DigitalOcean Guide](https://kenfavors.com/code/how-to-install-ipython-jupyter-notebook-on-ubuntu-16-04-using-vagrant/)

[Vagrant Refused to connect to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630631/vagrant-refused-via-browser)

This is my vagrant file at the moment; so I'm not sure how would I set the config to allow jupyter to run; because it's being denied access

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION ||= "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = confDir + "/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
customizationScriptPath = confDir + "/user-customizations.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.require_version '>= 2.1.0'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exist? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "/tmp/bash_aliases"
        config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
            s.inline = "awk '{ sub(\"\r$\", \"\"); print }' /tmp/bash_aliases > /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases"
        end
    end

    if File.exist? homesteadYamlPath then
        settings = YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath))
    elsif File.exist? homesteadJsonPath then
        settings = JSON::parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath))
    else
        abort "Homestead settings file not found in #{confDir}"
    end

    Homestead.configure(config, settings)

    if File.exist? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath, privileged: false, keep_color: true
    end

    if File.exist? customizationScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: customizationScriptPath, privileged: false, keep_color: true
    end

    if Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-hostsupdater')
        config.hostsupdater.aliases = settings['sites'].map { |site| site['map'] }
    elsif Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-hostmanager')
        config.hostmanager.enabled = true
        config.hostmanager.manage_host = true
        config.hostmanager.aliases = settings['sites'].map { |site| site['map'] }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's alright; I managed to finally find a solution by working it through putty.

By following ["Kratens Answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276612/remote-access-jupyter-notebook-from-windows?rq=1)

This was also a great reference to help with anybody having similar troubles;

[Getting Started with Vagrant on Windows](https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-vagrant-windows/)

hope it helps!